# Logical Comparison of Lists

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am trying to compare the columns in a data frame to a master list. I would like R to compare the values in each cell and output T if they match and F if they do not.

For example:

```
Master
m<-c(1,2,2,2,1)

Data
a<-c(1,2,2,2,2)
b<-c(1,1,1,1,1)
c<-c(1,1,2,2,2)
d<-cbind(a,b,c)

Result of comparing m to the columns in d
  a b c
1 T T T
2 T F F
3 T F T
4 T F T
5 F T F
```

How might I achieve a comparison with this sort of output?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply :

```
d==m

         a     b     c
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```